# Variable in checkbox id not passed in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, checkbox

I'm facing a problem with passing a variable to id attribute in JavaScript. The following script works with Chrome, but fails with IE, Edge, Android.

```
function add_file(selected_file) {
  if(document.compile_list[selected_file].checked == true){ 
    document.compile_list.selected_files.value += selected_file + ",";
  } 
  else {
    in_value = document.compile_list.selected_files.value; 
    name_comma = selected_file + ","; 
    res_value = in_value.replace(name_comma, "");
    document.compile_list.selected_files.value = res_value;
  }
}
```

The form input tag is as follows:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='2017_06_20_12_22_12' onChange='add_file("2017_06_20_12_22_12");'>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "The form input tag is as follows:". Did you miss that?

Comment: What is the definition of `document.compile_list` and `selected_files`? Generally avoid using direct member access for getting HTML elements, instead use `document.getElementById`.